# Group of permutations for reversible classical circuit on $n$ bits

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, logic, permutations

While discussing the relation of the model of reversible computing with quantum computing, my professor made a remark like:

> Consider the model of reversible classical circuits on $n$ bits, where the gates are (say) arbitrary permutations of the 8 values of 3 bits.   The total group of permutations that you can make in this case is the alternating group $A_{2^n}$ if $n$ is at least 4. (Exercise: Why are odd permutations impossible?)

Now I'm a bit confused here. Shouldn't the group of all possible permutations for $n$ bit be the [symmetric group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_group) $S_{2^n}$? I'm not sure why it's the alternating group and not the symmetric group. Moreover, why should $n$ be at least 4 and why aren't odd permutations allowed? Even some hints would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof that only even permutations can be achieved in this way if $n\ge4$ is essentially the proof of Lemma $11$ on page $8$ of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0207001.pdf). Obviously, if $n=3$, you have the entire $S_3$, so assume $n\ge4$. Then for each permutation that you can apply to $3$ bits, there's a bit that's left unaffected. The overall permutation thus decomposes into a permutation of the values with that bit set and a permutation of the values with that bit cleared, and these permutations have identical cycle structure. It follows that every cycle length occurs an even number of times in the overall permutation, and thus the overall permutation is even.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's a bit unclear to me what you mean by "in this way" in your first line. Which "way" do you mean? It's not mentioned that $n\times n$ gates are not allowed...or is that a common assumption in reversible computing?

Comment: @S.D.: By "in this way", I meant if you allow gates to perform arbitrary permutations of the $8$ values of any $3$ bits. That's what I thought you were asking about. If you want to allow $n\times n$ gates, then perhaps I misunderstood the question. What does the part about arbitrary permutations of the $8$ values of $3$ bits mean, then?

Comment: Does allowing $n\times n$ gates automatically exclude arbitrary permutations of n bits? Probably I'm missing something...Lemma 11 of the paper you cited says that $n\times n$ gates are not allowed

Comment: @S.D.: We seem to be talking past each other. I don't see how allowing something could exclude something. If you allow $n\times n$ gates, you can achieve whatever permutation you want. The proof of the lemma uses the fact that as long as every allowed operation leaves at least one bit invariant, the resulting overall permutation must be even. This applies to your case if you only want to allow operations on three (out of more than three) bits at a time, which is what I thought you wanted to do. If you want to allow $n\times n$ gates, you can implement all permutations, including odd ones.

Comment: Sorry, I myself misunderstood what my professor meant. Thanks a ton for the elaborate clarification. :)

Comment: By any chance, would be you able to answer [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3492694/replacing-a-large-arbitrary-permutation-gate-with-3-bit-arbitrary-permutation-ga)?