# Replacing a large arbitrary permutation gate with 3-bit arbitrary permutation gates

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, logic, permutations

Say I have a logic circuit of $n$ bits. And I have a reversible gate $G_n$ that can perform arbitrary (even) permutations of the values of these $n$ bits. Is it possible to replace this by some number of $3$-bit (arbitrary permutation) logic gates $G_3$? How?

(An example of a 3-bit permutation gate would be say the Toffoli. The $G_3$ and $G_n$ gates can perform *arbitrary* even permutations.)

P.S. For some more context see my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3492230/group-of-permutations-for-reversible-classical-circuit-on-n-bits).

Comment: Do you really mean "permutations of these $n$ bits"? In the other question that you link to, you were considering permutations of the values of those bits. That seemed to make more sense.

Comment: @joriki I mean "values", yes...typo

Comment: To clarify this for people who haven't dealt with the other question: This means that the gates apply a permutation of the $2^n$ possible values of the $n$ bits, not a permutation of the positions of the bits.

Comment: I believe this follows from Theorem $12$ on p. $9$ of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0207001.pdf) (since $C$, $N$ and $T$ operate on at most $3$ bits). The proof there is quite involved, though; it might be that using arbitrary $3$-bit gates allows for a simpler proof.

Comment: For those like me that haven't been introduced to Signor Toffoli : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toffoli_gate

Comment: @joriki That seems to be quite relevant. Do you also know any result that gives the lower bound for the number of C, N, T gates needed to create any arbitrary even permutation gates of (values of) n-bits?

Comment: @S.D.: I don't.